# Is it possible to send data to light sensor in android?

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager, light-sensor

I am working with sensors in my application in which I got stuck on a question is there any way to send data through the light sensor or to the light sensor in android programmatically?

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: do you know any thing about MQTT?

Comment: no. Is that helpful to communicate with sensors? @ManishAhire

Comment: Yes check these references about MQTT protocol

https://mqtt.org/

https://www.javatpoint.com/mqtt-protocol

Comment: If I change the screen brightness then the data of light sensor will be affected? @ManishAhire

Comment: please go through the document, all control is in your hand; yes i have worked on this technology it is the best in IOT.